# What does "Could not find or load main class", "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" , "run.xml:111" and " run.xml:95" mean?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a bug in my Java project.
I am working with the JTabbedPanel tool which I am adding several panels inside it. My error is that I have 52 panels and when I add this last one with labels inside it I get the following error (when compiling the project).
Any solution to this.
Here is my code:

````
Error: Could not find or load main class Vista.Modulos
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Vista.Modulos
C:\Users\Paulo\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.6\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Paulo\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.6\executor-snippets\run.xml:94: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)```
````

Comment: And the meaning of `run.xml:111` in `C:\Users\Paulo\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.6\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:` should be obvious.  It means "line 111 of that file".  Look at the file.

Comment: "Here is my code".  That's not code.  It looks like *excerpts* from a stack trace.  It is not sufficient to solve the problem, but you **should** be able to diagnose and solve the problem for yourself based on the information in the duplink.